# How To Get The Near By places of a specific items they are saved on a local database

Tags: xamarin, geolocation, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, geofencing

I have a List i want only the Near By places to show up on it ,
lets say in one mile radius. 
How can i do so? i searched the Internet A lot didn't find what i'm after i red a few topics about geo-financing  but i couldn't make it happen i just want a plugin 
or a logic to build one i tried many plugins no thing is working as i expected and they are not well documented i'm sure some of u have done it so please share it with me
can anyone help me please i'm working on Xamarin forums

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [nearby places](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) to geat the nearby places near the value that you want and place the marker using [Xamarin Form Maps](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/) if you wish to do so.

Comment: The locations i want my app to include are not for public use its some private places i have specified their locations so i dont think google maps/near by  wiill help right ?